# How to handle master actor failure

Tags: java, hadoop, akka

I am new to Akka, I built an Akka model which connects to HDFS, extracts data, process it and write the processed data back to HDFS. Now, If my master actor crashes then the corresponding child actors(Workers) will crash and the whole system has to restart.

So, if there is a process to create a secondary master which automatically comes into action as soon as the primary fails with minimal recovery time. I am not able to draw a clear picture around this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/supervision.html) :

> /user: The Guardian Actor
>
> The actor which is probably most interacted with is the parent of all
>   user-created actors, the guardian named "/user". Actors created using
>   system.actorOf() are children of this actor. This means that when this
>   guardian terminates, all normal actors in the system will be shutdown,
>   too. It also means that this guardian’s supervisor strategy determines
>   how the top-level normal actors are supervised. Since Akka 2.1 it is
>   possible to configure this using the setting
>   akka.actor.guardian-supervisor-strategy, which takes the
>   fully-qualified class-name of a SupervisorStrategyConfigurator. When
>   the guardian escalates a failure, the root guardian’s response will be
>   to terminate the guardian, which in effect will shut down the whole
>   actor system.

Your master is the top level actor in your application therefore he is a child of the user guardian, so he'll be restarted automatically because supervision for the Guardian is defaulting to :

```
  final val defaultDecider: Decider = {
    case _: ActorInitializationException ⇒ Stop
    case _: ActorKilledException         ⇒ Stop
    case _: DeathPactException           ⇒ Stop
    case _: Exception                    ⇒ Restart
  }
```

Comment: @user3840262 Well, then you understand you don't need to have another master. Maybe except if restarting your master is very costly and you can't afford to wait, then you could somehow mirror your master to another actor and wake him up when needed. Don't know it that much but maybe you could even look at Akka-Cluster with his failover capabilities. Could be overkill though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I got the concept of Guardian actor and how it supervises the user created actors. But, my question is whether there is any possible way to create more than one supervisor actor for the same job. So, that if for any reason one supervisor fails the other supervisor can take control and the job need not be restarted. My question is related to scalability & fault tolerance of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can have a supervisor, a child of the /user guardian, which can restart it's children in your case the master you are referring to. If there is anything that can cause an actor to get an exception it should be done by a child actor. The child actors can be restarted amongst other actions